# css grid to justify contents center if row is not full

Tags: html, css

So I was wondering if it was possible for `display: grid` to center its items at the center like a flexbox if the row isn't filled up.

Example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
 
  $("#main").append($("<div class='item'>test</div>"))
  $("#flex").append($("<div class='flex-item'>test</div>"))
}
```

```css
#main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}


#flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
</div>

<div id="flex">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply `auto` instead `1fr` in `grid-template-columns`. Then apply your desired width for your items. It will make the desired result.

```
 #main {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;  
}
.item {
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 100px;
   width:100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a75cqtrs/)

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to fix the column width then use the `vw` to apply dynamic width based on your screen.

```
.item {
   border: 1px solid black;
   content: "test";
   height: 100px;
   width:16vw;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a75cqtrs/1/)

Comment: I did want to keep the 1fr since it keeps the width at a correct size. However if it's not possible to do that then I'll accept your answer.